# disable everyone group from being applied to new printer additions

Tags: shared-printers

I would like to find a method to prevent the Everyone group from being applied to newly shared printers on a print server. Would like on admins and creator owner to be present so end users do not see the new printer before someone has a chance to apply particular user group for segregated access.

I haven't found any way to do this yet via registry or group policy but I may be looking in the wrong area?

Comment: Those are some fast users to be able to find a newly shared printer and print to it before new security permissions are applied.

Comment: Setup your printer shares with with powershell?  Do all the ACLs in a single step?

Comment: Well its to avoid user error on forgetting as well as doing mass scripted printer installs, last night I was adding printers at 1am and forgot one to update perms on one printer. Not a huge issue but a problem I want to deal with if possible.

Comment: Hey Zoredache I was actually just looking for the method of setting acl's on printers and I am not seeing how that works, get/set-acl doesn't appear to work for me. `get-acl "\\server\printer1" | set-acl "\\server\printer2" Online help for that function says it only applies to file and registry objects as far as I could tell.

Comment: figured out the permission using powershell 4 which meh, is great but not practical for the rest of the staff. `set-printer Test2 -PermissionSDDL $((get-printer test1 -full).PermissionSDDL)`